# Insert Record Dynamically from map

Tags: apex, field-mapping

I have a `Map<String,String>` containing `<field API Name, field value>`

Is there a way to insert them into an SObject that contains those field names exactly?

My SObject has hundreds of fields and I only want to insert those I have in the map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All SObjects offer [these methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) that include a `put` by field API name method so the values can be transferred like this:

```
Map<String, String> m = ...;    // Could also be Map<String, Object>
SObject sob = ...;

for (String f : m.keySet()) {
    sob.put(f, m.get(f));
}
```

Comment: can i also dynamically check the type of field and convert my value to that type? @Kieth C

Comment: would making my map<String,Object> solve that problem for me?

Comment: Using `Map<String, Object>` is a good way to go as it lets you insert values of type String, Decimal, Boolean etc with the type maintained when the values are put into the SObject.